# Is there a problem with the $\not\mathcal{R}$ command?

Tags: math-mode

Originally, I intended to use the command $\not\mathcal{R}$ as the negation of a binary relation, but there is a problem with that concatenation of commands. So I did what anyone would do in a situation like this, which is create my own symbol.Searching for information on this page, I came across the following code:

```
\newcommand{\TCNegacion}[1]{%
    \mathrel{\fbox{\ooalign{$#1$\cr\hidewidth\raisebox{0.5ex}{\rotatebox[origin]{80}{\rule{0.5cm}{0.5pt}}}\hidewidth\cr}}}
}
```

This code solves the initial problem, but it generates another one, namely the concatenation of commands `$y\TCNegation{\mathcal{T}} g$` is not to my liking. I'd like to rotate it a bit more to better visualize the negation, but I lose the alignment of the characters involved.

Is there a better way to fix the initial problem?

Is it possible to improve the code?

Comment: use the slanted  `\not` character rather than a rule?

Comment: From a design point of view, I would use the bar notation like in probability.

Answer (score 2):

You could tweak this some more but I'd use the slanted `\not` not a rule, with optional per-character offset

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\mfudge{4mu}
\def\fooA{\def\mfudge{7mu}}
\def\fooI{\def\mfudge{1mu}}
\def\fooM{\def\mfudge{8mu}}


\newcommand\foo[1]{\mathrel{%
  \csname foo#1\endcsname
  \mkern\mfudge
  \not{\mkern-\mfudge\mathcal{#1}}}}


\begin{document}


$\foo{A}$
 
$\foo{I}$
 
$\foo{M}$
 
$\foo{R}$
 
$\foo{Z}$
 

\end{document}
```

---

Two packages offering similar functionality are [slashed](https://ctan.org/pkg/slashed) and [centernot](https://ctan.org/pkg/centernot).

Comment: Since almost no `\mathcal` capitals have a descender ("Q" is the only exception), I'd be inclined to raise the `\not` just a bit, to appear more symmetrical.  The horizontal placement looks good as you have it, but would have to be adjusted a bit to the left if the overlay is shifted up.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I did wonder about that

Comment: Good thing that this and more is already available as a package https://ctan.org/pkg/slashed  :-)

Comment: @WillieWong Oh wow! Brilliant package, who wrote that!

Comment: Too bad it lacks documentation.

Comment: @barbarabeeton it does pre-date pdf by several years:-)

Comment: Could have shown an example in the README file.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I'm impressed that you think I remember my thought processes in 1987